# Drop Column Command Not Responding

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I would like to alter a column type from boolean to integer. I was having some trouble changing the type since when I ran the command nothing would happen, no error message, like the computer was in a loop. Another way is to just drop the column and just recreate it. I am running

```
alter table alarm drop column state;
```

But again, nothing is happening. Am I doing something wrong?

My other command was:

```
alter table alarm alter column state type integer;
```

Comment: Are there any open transactions on the database?

Comment: Was your SQL client still executing the query?  How much data have you got in the table?  Schema changes often take a long time since the data on disk may need to be moved.

Comment: How many records in your table?

Comment: Any error message/error code?

Comment: @jarlh >no error message

Comment: What @Mark is getting at is that the table may be locked if another connection is using the table.

Comment: @Mark No, there are open transactions

Comment: @MegaTron In that table, I deleted all records

Comment: @BaconBits: no, dropping a column is essentially a cost-free operation. No data is being "moved" around on disk in Postgres.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I didn't mean so much dropping the column as altering the datatype as in his second query.  Sorry I didn't make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

I had an open transaction occurring. I am using a Flask application and when I stopped the website, the command was able to run without issue.